# Download Firefox browser cache file

Tags: html, firefox, caching

I was working on a project and just when I saved the file, my power cut off. Now my `html` file is corrupted and I have no backup of it.

I just remembered that I might have a cache of it in Firefox. So, first I tried [CacheViewer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cacheviewer/) from Firefox official add-ons store. This add-on would install and then required a restart, after the restart it would disappear.

So instead, I tried the old fashioned way. I went to `about:cache` > `Local Storage` and whew,  I was lucky enough that it was there and wasn't replaced with the blank corrupted `html` file.

Now I have *some sort* (Catch Entry Information) of file. The left side has the binary code, while the right side has the proper `html` code with some unnecessary `.` periods in it.

This is what my this file looks like:

```
00000000:  3c  21  64  6f  63  74  79  70  65  20  68  74  6d  6c  3e  0d  <!doctype html>.
00000010:  0a  3c  68  74  6d  6c  3e  0d  0a  3c  68  65  61  64  3e  0d  .<html>..<head>.
00000020:  0a  3c  6d  65  74  61  20  63  68  61  72  73  65  74  3d  22  .<meta charset="
00000030:  75  74  66  2d  38  22  3e  0d  0a  3c  74  69  74  6c  65  3e  utf-8">..<title>
00000040:  46  69  74  41  70  70  3c  2f  74  69  74  6c  65  3e  0d  0a  FitApp</title>..
00000050:  3c  73  74  79  6c  65  3e  40  66  6f  6e  74  2d  66  61  63  <style>@font-fac
00000060:  65  20  7b  0a  20  20  66  6f  6e  74  2d  66  61  6d  69  6c  e {.  font-famil
00000070:  79  3a  20  22  52  6f  62  6f  74  6f  2d  6c  69  67  68  74  y: "Roboto-light
00000080:  22  3b  0a  20  20  73  72  63  3a  20  75  72  6c  28  22  2e  ";.  src: url(".
00000090:  2e  2f  66  6f  6e  74  73  2f  52  6f  62  6f  74  6f  2d  4c  ./fonts/Roboto-L
000000a0:  69  67  68  74  2e  74  66  66  22  29  20  66  6f  72  6d  61  ight.tff") forma
000000b0:  74  28  22  74  72  75  65  74  79  70  65  22  29  2c  20  6c  t("truetype"), l
000000c0:  6f  63  61  6c  28  22  52  6f  62  6f  74  6f  2d  6c  69  67  ocal("Roboto-lig
000000d0:  68  74  22  29  20  66  6f  72  6d  61  74  28  22  74  72  75  ht") format("tru
000000e0:  65  74  79  70  65  22  29  3b  0a  20  20  66  6f  6e  74  2d  etype");.  font-
000000f0:  77  65  69  67  68  74  3a  20  34  30  30  3b  0a  7d  0a  40  weight: 400;.}.@
```

How do I go about decoding this?

If there is a better way to download a catch file from Mozilla Firefox, please do mention.

Comment: http://www.acquireforensics.com/blog/mozilla-cache-folder.html

Answer (score 0):

Steps:

1. Copy all of that text into a text document, and save it.
2. Edit that text to make it only the column of hexadecimal characters.

   - Options for how to do this include shell commands, a find-replace using regex, or a column editing mode in your text editor.
3. Convert those hex encoded bytes into a binary file.

   - You should be able to paste those characters into any decent hex editor, and save it as a file.

BTW, the `.`'s in this case are substituted to replace the newline characters.